# Using custom scheduler for audio stream time

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

In sound processing applications, many events are timed off the audio stream time (which is, in the first approximation, simply a count of consumed samples multiplied by a coefficient), rather than system time, often called wall time in this scenario. For example, it is often desirable to time future events based on the stream time. For example, a timer can be scheduled to accept a recording if there has been no voice activity for certain amount of time; stream time is a better representation of time for this purpose than wall clock time.

I am thinking about using the `HistoricalScheduler` for timing such activities. As far as I understand, it runs all scheduled actions in the same thread that called `AdvanceBy/To`. Also, the whole application is under our control, in the sense that there are no 3rd party pieces--at least such that would use RX.

**Question 1:** Is this idea correct, ok, or incredibly silly? I understand RX by mind, have no experience with it, a *gut sense* if you wish.

The stream is delivered through .NET event callbacks. The thread that delivers stream buffers (and invokes the event) should better be blocked as little as possible. Audio is transferred into an endless buffer of finite length, and this actual buffering would happen in an observer for this event observing on a dedicated thread, and this is where scheduler time will advance. Essentially this comes down to

```
IDisposable _sub;

// The historic scheduler that reflects the time of 
// the last sample in the endless buffer.
HistoricalScheduler _hisch = new HistoricalScheduler();

// This must be disposed of.
EventLoopScheduler _eventLoopSch = new EventLoopScheduler();

public IScheduler StreamTimeScheduler => _hisch;

// Subscribing to the stream.
void Initialize() {
  _sub = Observable.FromEventPattern<TEventHandler, TEventArgs>(
                     h => ReceivedAudio += h,
                     h => ReceivedAudio -= h)
                   .ObserveOn(_eventLoopSch)
                   .Subscribe(b => Append(b));
}

// The function that puts samples into the endless buffer. 
void Append(byte[] sample) {
  // ...put the sample into the array...
  _hisch.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sample.Length / _avgBytesPerSecond));
}
```

**Question 2:** I feel weird advancing a scheduler from within an observing function, as in the example above. Is this an acceptable practice, or does it immediately smell fishy (or maybe it is somewhat in between the two extremes)?

Another possible complication is that the stream eventually stops producing data, and so does stream time.

**Question 3:** What, if any, are implications of stopping time in a scheduler, such that some scheduled actions will never execute and will remain in the queue forever? Will simply dropping a reference to the scheduler cause a disposable resource leak?

And also stream time differs from wall clock time.

**Question 4:** What, if any, are implications of different schedulers providing incoherent notion of `Now`?

My best guess here is "none at all," since the `HistoricScheduler` in other scenarios coexist with real time schedulers peacefully, but I am not sure I understand this part of RX well enough not to ask this question too.

Comment: You're asking a lot of broad questions here. And you're asking things in a confusing way - how does saying "complication (or a non-complication)" make it easier for us to understand. I think you need to create at least four specific questions (which include code) for us to give you straightforward specific answers. Right now this question is too hard to answer in a way that would be of benefit to anyone.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Thanks for the feedback. Do you think even #1 is unanswerable? That my idea of using `HistoryScheduler` as a scheduler based not on pre-recorded history but instead on a steady stream of *current* events is *not even wrong*? That would be a clear indication I understand nothing about RX.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I changed "complication (or a non-complication)" to "possible complication," if you think that would make more sense. I really do not know if it is, sorry.

Comment: I think you need to provide code to demonstrate what you're suggesting. The phrase "so that actual buffering would happen in an observer" seems to show that you don't understand Rx terribly well, so some code would make some sense of it for yourself and us. I think that using the historical scheduler is wrong, but again code will help clarify that.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Bingo, you are very right, I kept the buffering in mind but did not explain it at all. I reworded Qs 1 and 2, and added (more like pseudo)code. As for buffering, I just have to do that: audio comes in 160-sample buffers, and some consumers want 256 samples, timeshifted 128 samples each, other consumers have different requirements; no way that could have been done in a pure functional way, however I would have liked that!

Comment: @Enigmativity: and thanks for your help really. Looking back, I think my question was really incomprehensible (I am not implying that has changed, of course :)).

Comment: Just a quick note - don't do `.ObserveOn(new EventLoopScheduler())` as `EventLoopScheduler` is disposable - you need to explicitly dispose of it when done.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'll correct the post. But otherwise, do you think the idea is viable? And, provided that I'll use the `HistoricalScheduler` this way chiefly with `Observable.Timer()`, will stopping time cause any resource leaks?

Comment: It doesn't sound right to use the historical scheduler that way. I think we'd really need to see a full code sample to see if were viable.